# What is the difference between a reset and delete

Tags: itunes, ipod, macos, ipod-nano

I have a problem with my iPod nano which plays a track initially and later skips to the next track. I tried the same track in itunes v12 and it plays with ease. I had asked for this [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/163566/unable-to-play-a-complete-track-in-ipod-nano) for which I got an answer as to try doing the reset+delete all.

But my doubt is that if I am doing the reset (which I have done) then am I not in-directly deleting all the songs+the voice over

If I am wrong with the above then could please tell me what exactly is the difference in the reset and the delete

Answer (score 1):

When you reset you basically restarting the hardware and the device reloads the software.

When you delete you remove all the data from the device.

Though to solve your problem I would suggest you try the following:

Use iTunes to Restore your iPod to factory default. Once complete reload your content.

when you restore you erase the device completely and it reinstalls a new copy of the software to the device.

Regards

Kyle